# Is there a more effective way to check if a number is prime using recursive function?

Tags: scala, recursion, primes

I am writing a recursive function to check if a non-negative Integer is Prime in SCALA. My function takes two inputs to do so. Here is my code:

```
import io.StdIn._
def isPrime (x:Int, i:Int): Boolean = {
  if (i < 3) {
    true
  }else if (x % i == 0) {
    false
  }else{
    isPrime(x,i-1)
  }
}

print("Enter a number to check if it is a prime number: " )
val num1 = readInt()
println(isPrime(num1,num1-1))
```

My question is that is there a way for me to take one input as the parameter for the function? The code has to use a recursive function. I know that there are more effective ways to check if a number is prime (using iteration perhaps), but I'm just doing this as a practice problem.

Comment: Define effective. You can precompute primes and then check cache, you might want to search numbers with requirement that no cache exists, you can operate under memory constraints or optimize entirely for speed. Depending on requirements, we could answer that.

Comment: I think your function calls 4 a prime.

Comment: if you are talking about time complexity, I would suggest you to only divide number upto it's sqrt, else you can also look for sieve of eratosthenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine, I'd say even standard practice, to wrap recursive functions with a calling function. For example:

```
def isPrime( x:Int ) = { 
  def recIsP( n:Int, i:Int ) : Boolean = i == n || n % i != 0 && recIsP(n, i + 1) 
  recIsP(x,2) 
}

isPrime(3301)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make an inner method

```
def isPrime(x:Int): Boolean = {
  def loop(i: Int): Boolean = 
    if (i<3 ) {
      true
    } else if (x % i==0) {
      false
    } else {
      isPrime(x,i-1)
    }
  loop(x, x - 1)
}
```

another option is to make a default parameter. Those can't refer back to the previous parameter, so you'll have to use a workaround. Here I pass some `j`, and make `i = x - j`, so I can just increment `j` starting from 1

```
def isPrime(x: Int, j: Int = 1): Boolean = {
  val i = x - j
  if (i < 3) {
    true
  } else if (x % i==0) {
    false
  } else {
    isPrime(x, j + 1)
  }
}
```

Unrelatedly, there is a bug in your code: 4 should not be prime.